# attempt to create saveOrUpdate event with null entity

Tags: hibernate, spring, gwt

I have a GWT app that makes an RPC call to a server to save/create a new entity. However, the Spring-Hibernate back-end throws an exception with the following error message:

```
attempt to create saveOrUpdate event with null entity
```

I'm not sure what that means. What's null? If it's a new entity I am saving, I am expecting to have the `id` field be `null` or possibly `0`, and then have hibernate fill it. Is this expectation correct?

Comment: Could we see your mapping file and your entity?

Comment: Zoidberg,

Doesn't seem to be a mapping file to entity issue. It def seems to be a serialization issue like Andre brings up below.

So in GWT I initiate a RPC service in composite based class A, then in another sub-window (think popup) I initiate the RPC service class again. I the sub-window class i can get all entities of type A just fine but no update, save, or delete is successfull.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

`null entity` could mean that `saveOrUpdate()` is actually receiving `null` as an argument, ie:

```
session.saveOrUpdate(null);
```

If you're using serialization to pass to object to a remote location (you mentioned RPC), perhaps you should check if serialization is working correctly. Something tells me that failing to serialize might end up with a null reference being passed.

Comment: Andre,

Both back-end entity and GWT client Entity are serialized.

By the way, I can successfully create/save the entity if I run within Eclipse project through Spring beans. But when I run same code from GWT Hosted mode, I get the exception thrown. I can also create/save other entities just fine. weird.

Comment: So you mean this error happens only with this specific entity? saveOrUpdate() on others works fine?

Comment: Yup. I am starting to thinking it's a rpc proxy issue. See, I have Widget A where I initiate a RPC service. In widget A, I instantiate another widget, widget B. When I do I pass to widget B the RPc service from widget A.

Comment: Andre, thanks for the help. I found what was wrong. I have a code mistake in the code for mapping client gwt entity to back-end entity.

Comment: It happened to me that the object passed in was a `null` object in certain conditions. So I had to check for `null` before passing the object and executing the method. If it is `null` the execution is skipped. Your answer has been a helpful hint to realize that.